# How to pass Map to Oracle PL/SQL function?

Tags: java, oracle, data-structures

I would like to create an equivalent if this Java method as PL/SQL function in Oracle 10g:

```
String myMethod(int par1, Map<String, Object> par2);
```

Is it possible to pass a Map (or some simillar structure) to Oracle PL/SQL function? I have to be able to call this function from Java somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [interesting discussion on AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3696816290928) about passing java objects to Oracle. In particular IMO, this excellent [advice from Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3696816290928#10312235450701):

> Me, I would juse
>
> create global temporary table gtt (
>   fname varchar2(20), lname varchar2(20)
>   ) on commit delete rows;
>
> and have the java app BATCH insert
>   into this and then call the procedure,
>   the procedure just uses  that tables
>   data as its inputs.
>
> that, in my experience, is the least
>   amount of code between "me" and "being
>   finished"

i-e: just use a set of relational temporary tables, write into it with java and let pl/sql read from the tables. It will probably be nearly as efficient (as passing objects) and it will be orders of magnitude easier to implement and debug.

Comment: Use a temporary table is just what I was typing in too /+: you beat me to it.
There is also a tedious way to do it using built-in functions..

Answer (score 2):

[Down this path](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraoot.htm) lies horror and despair. I have seen it.

Comment: This is a huge exaggeration. I've been working with JPublisher conversions between PL/SQL and Java objects and it's quite easy to be picked up by developers who haven't used it before.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this article on JDBC interface for Oracle collections first](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraarr.htm)

Basically for complex objects you should use [JPublisher](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/toc.htm) to automatically generate the Java classes and the boilerplate code. Otherwise, a simple oracle.sql.ARRAY should do.

Note that you also need to create matching PL/SQL objects too, read [this article](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjint.htm#sthref39). You don't need to implement any MEMBER methods for just passing around data between Java and Oracle.

---

Edit 1: Unfortunately, PL/SQL does not have a Map concept like Java. However, you can model a Map as a special (Key,Value) object or as an Index-by table for simple class (sort of like a hash map).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is the way to pass collection of elements to a function. What I need is to pass a map. I do not know keys or number of entries in this map up front. Is it doable this way?